# Enlarge image by clicking on it using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I enlarge an image by clicking on it using jQuery. I'm pretty new to this and feel like I'm going in circles, please help.
Thanks!

Here's the HTML portion:

```
  <div class="box"> 
    <img id="image1" src="css/images/smallknife.png"> 
    <p>$50.00</p> 
  </div> 

<div id="dialog" style="display: none;"> 
  <img src="css/images/smallknife.png"> 
</div>
```

And this is the jQuery portion

```
$('#image1').click(function(){
        $("#dialog").dialog();
    });
```

Answer (score 12):

Might you be looking for a lightbox plugin like fancybox?

http://fancybox.net/

Answer (score 4):

Barebones code:

```
$(function ()
{
    $('#my-image').on('click', function ()
    {
        $(this).width(1000);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/YbMTg/

Comment: Thanks, can I use the .dialog or similar widget from jQuery to enlarge the image?

Comment: The answer is almost always "yes," but I've got no context for your question. Why haven't you shown any code yet?

Answer (score 3):

Here is some basic use.

```
var $img = $('img'); // finds all image tags

$img.click(function resize(e) { // bind click event to all images
  $img.css({ // resize the image
     height: '300px',
     width: '300px'
  });
});
```

if you are looking to bind the click event to one specific image, give the image and `id`
and cache like this

`var $img = $('#imageID');`

Answer (score 2):

This is the method I would use at it's most simple level to enlarge an image with a smooth transition:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
   $("img").click(function(){    
        $("img").animate({height: "300px"});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

after searching and searching i found myself a way to do without using external JS source and no problems with licensing. positioning absolute and setting width and height to 100%, play with ocupacy of a div and there it is. I needed to create extra table to be able to center the image, did not work on div. and don't forget z-index to place the div and table above all other elements. cheers...

```
function enlargeimage(x)
  {   
      var a = document.getElementById('_enlargeimg');
      a.style.height = x + '%';
      a.style.width = x + '%';
      x++;    
      if (x < 90)
      { setTimeout("enlargeimage(\"" + x + "\")", 5);}
  }

  function reduceimage(x)
  {   
      var a = document.getElementById('_enlargeimg');
      a.style.height = x + '%';
      a.style.width = x + '%';
      x--;

      if (x > 0)
      { setTimeout("reduceimage(\"" + x + "\")", 5);}
      else
      {
          b = document.getElementById('_enlargediv');
          c = document.getElementById('_enlargetable');
          b.parentNode.removeChild(b);
          c.parentNode.removeChild(c);        
          document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
      }
  }
      function createelements(imgfile)
      {

          var divbackground = document.createElement('div');
          divbackground.setAttribute('id', '_enlargediv');
          divbackground.style.width  = '100%';
          divbackground.style.height = '100%';
          divbackground.style.position= 'absolute';
          divbackground.style.background= '#000';
          divbackground.style.left= '0';
          divbackground.style.top= '0';
          divbackground.style.opacity= 0.7;
          divbackground.style.zIndex= '1';

          document.body.appendChild(divbackground);

          var tblbackground = document.createElement('table');
          tblbackground.setAttribute('id', '_enlargetable')
          tblbackground.style.width  = '100%';
          tblbackground.style.height = '100%';
          tblbackground.style.position= 'absolute';       
          tblbackground.style.left= '0';
          tblbackground.style.top= '0';       
          tblbackground.style.zIndex= '2';
          tblbackground.style.textAlign = 'center';
          tblbackground.style.verticalAlign = 'middle';
          tblbackground.setAttribute('onClick', 'reduceimage(90)');

          var tr = tblbackground.insertRow();
          var td = tr.insertCell();

          var nimg = document.createElement('img');
          nimg.setAttribute('src', imgfile);
          nimg.setAttribute('id', '_enlargeimg');
          nimg.style.width='0px';
          nimg.style.height='0px'
          nimg.style.borderRadius = '5px';

          td.appendChild(nimg);

          document.body.appendChild(tblbackground);
          document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';        

          enlargeimage(0);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is kind of old, but in case anyone else stumbles across it, this is how to make the image enlarge in a jquery dialog.

```
$('img').on('click', function (){
    $('body').append('<div id="dialog" title="Image"><img src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" width="300" /></div>');
    $('#dialog').dialog();
});
```

Make sure you have the jquery-ui.css available otherwise it will look funny.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice code snippet that will toggle the image size between 120px wide and 400px wide, with a nice slow animation onclick.

```
$("img").toggle(function()
    {$(this).animate({width: "400px"}, 'slow');},
    function()
    {$(this).animate({width: "120px"}, 'slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I opted for the simplemodal jquery plugin. It included all what I need and is super simple to use.

[Using SimpleModal (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761261/simplemodal-click-to-show-image)